# Bootstrap: How can I keep input form and button inline below 768px breakpoint?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to put a search form with button next to it in the top row of my page, over to the right. Following advice from various posters here I have done this:

```
            <div class="row">
                <a class="navbar-brand " href="#">Brand</a>     
                <div class="input-group pull-right">
                    <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">OK</button>
                        </span>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This works fine - until I hit the 768px breakpoint, when the button drops below the input field. And I can't see why it should do this or what i am getting wrong.

Comment: when you say *the top row* do you mean you want the form within the navbar?

Comment: Actually what I am trying to do (and being new to Bootstrap, so I'm going at it little by little), is this.
I want a top bar to the site which is made up of three rows.
In the top row accessibility links to left, search bar to right. In middle row, branding. In bottom row, horizontal menu. Ideally, in phone mode I would like the search bar to stay where it is and the accessibility links to be replaced by the hamburger (top left) which would then open the menu as accordeons immediately underneath it.

Answer (score 4):

*I found a topic that can help you: 
**[Fixed search bar with Bootstrap 3.0](http://www.mentful.com/2014/06/22/fixed-search-navbar-with-bootstrap-3-0/)***

But I make a suggestion for you, *you can checkout from this link*: http://jsfiddle.net/kdvd4x7t/

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>     
            <div class="col-md-2 pull-right">
                <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="search" />
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: That seems to work fine. I guess the trick is putting the input-group div inside the form instead of around it. Hmmm... Not very obvious at all. Many thanks